# How does typecasting/polymorphism work with this nested, closure type in Swift?

Tags: swift, casting, polymorphism

I know that `(Int) -> Void` can't be typecasted to `(Any) -> Void`:

```
let intHandler: (Int) -> Void = { i in
    print(i)
}
var anyHandler: (Any) -> Void = intHandler <<<< ERROR
```

This gives:

> error: cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> Void' to specified type
>   '(Any) -> Void'

---

**Question**: But I don't know why this work?

```
let intResolver: ((Int) -> Void) -> Void = { f in
    f(5)
}

let stringResolver: ((String) -> Void) -> Void = { f in
    f("wth")
}

var anyResolver: ((Any) -> Void) -> Void = intResolver
```

I messed around with the return type and it still works...:

```
let intResolver: ((Int) -> Void) -> String = { f in
    f(5)
    return "I want to return some string here."
}

let stringResolver: ((String) -> Void) -> Void = { f in
    f("wth")
}

var anyResolver: ((Any) -> Void) -> Any = intResolver (or stringResolver)
```

Sorry if this is asked before. I couldn't find this kind of question yet, maybe I don't know the keyword here.
Please enlighten me!

*If you want to try: https://iswift.org/playground?wZgwi3&v=3*

Comment: I'm interested in hearing the answer to this one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all about [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) and Swift closures.

Swift is covariant in respect to closure return type, and contra-variant in respect to its arguments. This makes closures having the same return type or a more specific one, and same arguments or less specific, to be compatible.

Thus `(Arg1) -> Res1` can be assigned to `(Arg2) -> Res2` if `Res1: Res2` and `Arg2: Arg1`.

To express this, let's tweak a little bit the first closure:

```
import Foundation

let nsErrorHandler: (CustomStringConvertible) -> NSError = { _ in
    return NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
}
var anyHandler: (Int) -> Error = nsErrorHandler
```

The above code works because `Int` conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`, while `NSError` conforms to `Error`. `Any` would've also work instead of `Error` as it's even more generic.

Now that we established that, let's see what happens in your two blocks of code.

The first block tries to assign a more specific argument closure to a less specific one, and this doesn't follow the variance rules, thus it doesn't compile.

How about the second block of code? We are in a similar scenario as in the first block: closures with one argument.

- we know that `String`, or `Void`, is more specific that `Any`, so we can use it as return value
- `(Int) -> Void` is more specific than `(Any) -> Void` (closure variance rules), so we can use it as argument

The closure variance is respected, thus `intResolver` and `stringResolver` are a compatible match for `anyResolver`. This sounds a little bit counter-intuitive, but still the compile rules are followed, and this allows the assignment.

Things complicate however if we want to use closures as generic arguments, the variance rules no longer apply, and this due to the fact that Swift generics (with few exceptions) are invariant in respect to their type: `MyGenericType<B>` can't be assigned to `MyGenericType<A>` even if `B: A`. The exceptions are standard library structs, like `Optional` and `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's consider exactly why your first example is illegal:

```
let intHandler: (Int) -> Void = { i in
    print(i)
}
var anyHandler: (Any) -> Void = intHandler
// error: Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> Void' to specified type '(Any) -> Void'
```

An `(Any) -> Void` is a function that can deal with *any* input; an `(Int) -> Void` is a function that can *only* deal with `Int` input. Therefore it follows that we cannot treat an `Int`-taking function as a function that can deal with *anything*, because it can't. What if we called `anyHandler` with a `String`?

What about the other way around? This is legal:

```
let anyHandler: (Any) -> Void = { i in
  print(i)
}
var intHandler: (Int) -> Void = anyHandler
```

Why? Because we can treat a function that deals with *anything* as a function that can deal with `Int`, because if it can deal with anything, by definition it must be able to deal with `Int`.

So we've established that we can treat an `(Any) -> Void` as an `(Int) -> Void`. Let's look at your second example:

```
let intResolver: ((Int) -> Void) -> Void = { f in
    f(5)
}

var anyResolver: ((Any) -> Void) -> Void = intResolver
```

Why can we treat a `((Int) -> Void) -> Void` as an `((Any) -> Void) -> Void`? In other words, why when calling `anyResolver` can we forward an `(Any) -> Void` argument onto an `(Int) -> Void` parameter? Well, as we've already found out, we can treat an `(Any) -> Void` as an `(Int) -> Void`, thus it's legal.

The same logic applies for your example with `((String) -> Void) -> Void`:

```
let stringResolver: ((String) -> Void) -> Void = { f in
  f("wth")
}

var anyResolver: ((Any) -> Void) -> Void = stringResolver
```

When calling `anyResolver`, we can pass an `(Any) -> Void` to it, which then gets passed onto `stringResolver` which takes a `(String) -> Void`. And a function that can deal with anything is also a function that deals with strings, thus it's legal.

Playing about with the return types works:

```
let intResolver: ((Int) -> Void) -> String = { f in
  f(5)
  return "I want to return some string here."
}

var anyResolver: ((Any) -> Void) -> Any = intResolver
```

Because `intResolver` says it returns a `String`, and `anyResolver` says it returns `Any`; well a string *is* `Any`, so it's legal.